# Android how to add opening Animation to a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-animation

I simply want to implement an animation to a listview opening.
My listview just goes to visible to unvisible when I press the button but without animation.
I have a button on right center of the screen and when I press this I want to open a small listview from sliding right to left and pushing button to the center too.

I already have one drawer but this one is not exactly like drawer.
Is there any other way without using navigation drawer again?

Thank you for all.

Comment: What you have tried @Kadir

Comment: You should learn and try android transition

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/building-animations-android-transition-framework-part-1/

Comment: @MiteshVanaliya Thank you so much I was looking for something like this.But is that library can be used with Activity or just for fragments ?